# Is it possible to automate windows calculator using excel VBA?

Tags: excel, automation, calculator, vba

I just recently started VBA and I am tasked to automate a table creation process using Excel. I have no problem with regards to automating procedures inside excel workbook itself but I also need to automate programs outside excel.

To gather data, I need to control a certain program(to open a file, click the next button, select "OK" for the popout and and save the file as CSV). I figured that these steps may be the same as controlling window's calculator (Instructing VBA to press the "9" button or any button of my choice) thus the reason for this question. So in line with this, I was wondering if it's possible to automate windows calculator(telling the calculator which buttons to press) with excel VBA?

If it is, please do provide me with the syntax or suggestions. I'd appreciate it if the terminologies are not so technical as I'm quite new to the programming world. Many thanks!

Comment: Controlling programs by automating their UI is notoriously finicky. If you must use that procedure, I suggest a language designed for that purpose, e.g. https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/ AutoIT has a basic-like syntax, so should be easy to pick up with your VBA experience.

Comment: ***Welcome to Stack Oveflow!*** You want to know how to programmatically control Windows `calc.exe` so that you'll know how to programmatically control a *different* application?  Is that correct?  Can you expand a bit more on you "end-goal"? (ie, what are you ultimately trying to accomplish?)  Also, check out "[mcve]" as well as "[these tips](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/writing-the-perfect-question/)".

Comment: @ashleedawg Thank you and yes, basically the end point of this is to be able to automatically "press" buttons and toolbars of an application(In this case, calc.exe) using VBA

Comment: One of us are confused: If the application that you ultimately want to be able to control programmatically is `calc.exe`: ***why?*** You can do math in VBA without any outside programs. Or, if you think that by learning how to control `calc.exe`, you'll know how to control other applications: that just doesn't make sense for a number of reasons. It would be extremely helpful if you could [edit] you question to add a screenshot or two of what you're trying to do, as well as *some* evidence that you've at least tried to figure this out on your own, before posting. Did you visit the links above?

Comment: @ashleedawg Hello again. Sorry, I was working on analogy as I'm not sure if I can post screenshot of the said program online therefore I have no other methods other than comparing it to calc.exe(as this is the closest program that it can get with its multiple buttons). For the code, I have no code for it yet as I'm not sure if it's possible to control calc.exe or not(thus the question). I did read what you posted(the first link being is displayed before creating a question and the second, I didn't know what else could I possibly add)

Comment: That's my point - analogy's won't work.  Controlling each app is different.  (Or is this actually homework?!)  :-)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a scripting program is necessary as values have to be assigned to certain buttons for it to be controlled. The first answer from Eric J. is most appropriate and he also provided a link for a free scripting program. Posting his answer in this post for references.

"Controlling programs by automating their UI is notoriously finicky. If you must use that procedure, I suggest a language designed for that purpose, e.g. autoitscript.com/site/autoit AutoIT has a basic-like syntax, so should be easy to pick up with your VBA experience. – Eric J."